# How to change the number of digits displayed from median_test in ggplot annotate in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a statistical test result from median_test that I have been plotting as text using ggplot-annotate, but using typical options for changing the number of digits shown will only change the results shown in the console, and not the text-plot.

For example:

```
options(digits = 3)
medtest <- median_test(LOS ~ Group, data)
medtest
```

Will produce the below in the console:

```
    Asymptotic Two-Sample Brown-Mood Median Test
    data:  LOS by Group (L, N)
    Z = 36, p-value <2e-16
    alternative hypothesis: true mu is not equal to 0
```

However, when I create a text plot of this with the below code, it shows the maximum number of digits (see below image):

```
options(digits = 3)
medtest <- median_test(LOS ~ Group, data)

text = paste("Mood's Median Test:","\n",
  "Z: ", medtest@statistic@teststatistic ,"\n",
             "p-value: ", pvalue(medtest))

ggplot() +
  annotate("text", x = 0.5, y = 0, size=4, label = text, hjust = 0.5) +
  theme_void()
```

[image of ggplot median_test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2L83.png)

Does anyone know how to change the number of digits shown in the ggplot annotate output?

Thank you!

Comment: Where does the `median_test` function come from? It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Sorry - library (coin) is used for median_test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using round(). It is base R and will always allow you to set the number of digits you want

```
round(1.1111111, 2)
```

> 1.11